# How to scroll to a certain point in the document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

As an example, I use this page: http://www.bulldoggin.com/home/

As you can see, there's no way to just scroll, each time you scroll it automatically jumps to a certain point in the document. There's no way to go "halfway".

Is there a way to solve this using javascript, jQuery or anything? I don't want to use buttons to jump to a certain point of the page, but I want to achieve this by scrolling, using the mouse-wheel, the arrow-down-key etc.?

Comment: On this page the scroll event is catched to be canceled then remplaced by a full page scrolling, so if you don't want this effect, do not cancel native scroll (it's always a bad idea)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code snippet that does what you want, it still needs a lot of work but it should help you get started.

```js
var lastScrollTop = 1;
var doneScrolling = true;

$(window).scroll(function(event){
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (doneScrolling == true) {
   doneScrolling = false
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
     $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("p").offset().top
    }, 2000, function(){
     doneScrolling = true
    });
   } else {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("p").last().offset().top
    }, 2000, function(){
     doneScrolling = true
    });
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 1000px;
}

p {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>Test 1</p>
  <p>Test 2</p>
  <p>Test 3</p>
  <p>Test 4</p>
  <p>Test 5</p>
  <p>Test 6</p>
  <p>Test 7</p>
  <p>Test 8</p>
  <p>Test 9</p>
  <p id="last">Test 10</p>
</div>
```